# Strange behaviour when receiving data

Tags: android, json, input, bufferedreader

I'm developing an Android app that requires me to get some data from the server, this data is comes as **JSON data**, I have to receive like **7** `JSON Objects`, I'm using regular socket programming to get this data, and I get it by launching a thread that will wait for a data to come from the server.

I'm using the following method:

```
public String getServerRespons() throws JSONException {

        String responseLine, server_response = null_string;

        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        int count = 0;
        boolean first = true;
        try {
            while (true)
                    {
                if((responseLine = input.readLine()) == null){
                    break;
                }
                first = false;
                server_response = server_response + responseLine;
                //
                // some processing to make sure it's a valid JSON
                //
                if(count == 0){ // related to the Processing Lines result
                    System.out.println(server_response);
                    return response; // when commenting that line everything is ok
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Login.errorMessage.setText(conn_err);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

With that way i got like only **two** or **three** `JSON Objects` of the **seven** ones. BUT, when commenting the `return` Line and let it completes with the receiving process I got all the seven Objects efficiently and each Object is separated which makes me make sure that the processing i made to validate the JSON is going so well.

Answer (score 0):

I think int count is always 0 in your example so the return statement is always hit.